# Multiple cursors in a web app - how to display them?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I'm working on an app for scheduling projects. One of its main features should be displaying currently logged users' cursors in realtime. Like in Figma:

[image: figma-cursors]

On the backend, I'm going to use Firebase Realtime Database, where I'm gonna store mouse cursor coordinates. But, I've got a problem with the frontend part - I'm wondering what will be the best approach when it comes to the way of displaying them?

The most common solution is to use html canvas, but I'm afraid that this will mean, that I'll have to totally rebuild my app frontend ;)

So maybe just some small divs / svg elements representing other users' cursors? With this solution, I'm afraid that cursors will cover interface elements, so it will not be possible to click on those elements. Maybe it will require playing with z-index?

Please let me know, what in your opinion will be the best approach.

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` ignores clicks

Comment: Yes, an SVG with position absolute will work,..  I would also use WebSockets to echo the other users cursors..

Comment: @epascarello yeah, exactly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas is the best option here. You can use it as a layer above the rest of the page and as mentioned in the comments set `pointer-events :none;` to make sure it doesn't interfer with the other page functionalities.

Changing multiple SVGs positions in high frequency sounds inefficient performance wise, it will send the render process to reflow stage.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/faressoft/36cdd64faae21ed22948b458e6bf04d5) is a great explanation of the browser render process

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/How_browsers_work) you can find the following explanation:

> To ensure smooth scrolling and animation, everything occupying the main thread, including calculating styles, along with reflow and paint, must take the browser less than 16.67ms to accomplish. At 2048 X 1536, the iPad has over 3,145,000 pixels to be painted to the screen. That is a lot of pixels that have to be painted very quickly. To ensure repainting can be done even faster than the initial paint, the drawing to the screen is generally broken down into several layers. If this occurs, then compositing is necessary.
>
> Painting can break the elements in the layout tree into layers. Promoting content into layers on the GPU (instead of the main thread on the CPU) improves paint and repaint performance. There are specific properties and elements that instantiate a layer, including  and , and any element which has the CSS properties of opacity, a 3D transform, will-change, and a few others. These nodes will be painted onto their own layer, along with their descendants, unless a descendant necessitates its own layer for one (or more) of the above reasons.
>
> Layers do improve performance, but are expensive when it comes to memory management, so should not be overused as part of web performance optimization strategies.

(Meaning that you can create a layer for SVGs, but you'll have to use `transform` to move them around instead of `top`/`left`)

Best of luck with your project:)